# AWS MSK Connect how to install Rest API

Tags: aws-msk-connect

I have created multiple AWS MSK Connectors using Terraform, I came to know we can also use Rest API to update capacity configurations. Everywhere it says http://localhost:8083 but not sure how to use API. My MSK Cluster is running 9094 so it is definitely cannot use Rest API with port 8083.

I googled everywhere but was not able to find anything to connect to connector and enable 8083 port.

Need input is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Rest API port 8083 is available when you self-manage Kafka Connect. MSK Connect is a managed service. It doesn't expose a port 8083.

If you would like to use provisioned capacity and need to update the max number of workers, you will need to redeploy your connector with new parameters for scale config.

Make sure to create a connector with explicit predefined value for [offset topic name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-workers.html#msk-connect-manage-connector-offsets) and with the same connector name (this will cover both source and sink connectors use cases). This will make your connector to pick up from the previous state.